# Change div width in Laravel blade using expression or jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, laravel

I want to dynamically change width value of div element. Div contains blocks and the size of them depends on variable. For example if `$t->spotdiff = 2` I'd have two blocks separated equally 50/50% in column, if `$t->spotdiff = 10`, then I'd have 10 smaller blocks and so on...

This is my blade:

```
@foreach($test as $t)
...
<table>
...
<tr>
<td>
@for($i = 0; $ i < $t->spotdiff; $i++)
    <div id="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="cursor:pointer;float:left;background:#c0c0c0;height:18px;margin-right:1px;"></div>@endfor<span style="color:#fd8809">{{$t->spotdiff}}
@endfor
</td>
</tr>
...
</table>
...
@endforeach
```

I was trying to set it using Blade (I'm not actually sure if expressions could be written like this):

```
<div id="modal" style="witdh: {{(100 / $t->spotdiff)}}"></div>
```

Or with jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#modal").css("width", "{{(100 / $t->spotdiff)}}");
</script>
```

But without success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have spelling mistake,

1) Direct way

```
<div id="modal" style="width: {{(100 / $t->spotdiff)}}px"></div>
```

2) JQUERY WAY

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#modal").css("width", "{{(100 / $t->spotdiff)}}px");
</script>
```

Give it a try, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't target any legacy browsers you could easily achieve the effect of equal spreading of columns with CSS and [Flexbox](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp). This gives you an advantage of code and a view separation.

```css
.columns {
  display: flex;
}
.columns div {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
</div>
```